# getting max sublist based on value from other list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, nested-lists

want to get sublist which has max value on specified index based on condition.

```
mainlist=[[['RD-2', 'a', 120], ['RD-2', 'b', 125], ['RD-2', 'c', 127]], [['RD-3', 'a', 120], ['RD-3', 'b', 140]], [['RD-5', 'a', 120]],[['RD-7', 'a', 122]]]
```

and another list

```
baselist=[['RD-2', 100],['RD-3', 200],['RD-5', 240]]
```

for every first sub-element in baselist, i need the 1 complete sublist from mainlist which has max value in 2nd index position.
the output should be

```
flist=[['RD-2', 'c', 127],['RD-3', 'b', 140],['RD-5', 'a', 120]]
```

help me.

Comment: Interesting problem. Have you tried anything?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog: tried with forloop from baselist but was unable to apply logic to mainlist to get the max sublist.

Comment: It is great that you already tried something! If you can show us what you tried, and the error that you got, we can better understand and help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
flist = []               
for item in baselist: 
     for i in mainlist:       
         if i[0][0] ==item[0]:               
             flist.append(max(i, key=lambda x:x[2]))
```

the `flist` will be:

```
[['RD-2', 'c', 127], ['RD-3', 'b', 140], ['RD-5', 'a', 120]]
```

you can also use `itertools.product` to simplyfy `for` loops a little:

```
from itertools import product    

flist = []               
for i, item in product(mainlist,baselist):      
     if i[0][0] ==item[0]:               
          flist.append(max(i, key=lambda x:x[2]))
```

or also in just one line:

```
flist = [max(i, key=lambda x:x[2]) for i, item in product(mainlist,baselist) if i[0][0] == item[0]]
```

Comment: your welcome @learningstudent, please consider this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

A bit more compact but with the same outcome using list comprehension:

```
max_entries = [max(x, key=lambda x:x[2]) for x in mainlist]
flist = [max_entry for max_entry in max_entries for base_entry in baselist if max_entry[0]==base_entry[0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way using a list comprehension:

```
base = list(zip(*baselist))[0]
[max(i, key=lambda x:x[2]) for i in mainlist if i[0][0] in base]
[['RD-2', 'c', 127], ['RD-3', 'b', 140], ['RD-5', 'a', 120]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would first store you max lists in a dictionary, then just reference that dictionary later to build the new list:

```
from operator import itemgetter

mainlist = [
    [["RD-2", "a", 120], ["RD-2", "b", 125], ["RD-2", "c", 127]],
    [["RD-3", "a", 120], ["RD-3", "b", 140]],
    [["RD-5", "a", 120]],
    [["RD-7", "a", 122]],
]

baselist = [["RD-2", 100], ["RD-3", 200], ["RD-5", 240]]

d = {}
for sublist in mainlist:
    k = sublist[0][0]
    d[k] = max(sublist, key=itemgetter(2))

flist = [d.get(k) for k, _ in baselist]

print(flist)
# [['RD-2', 'c', 127], ['RD-3', 'b', 140], ['RD-5', 'a', 120]]
```